# a.ForEach vs. for (Type a: collection)

Tags: java

When playing with iterations, netbeans recommended using a functional approach to iteration.

The original method was:

```java
for (Type obj : collection) {
    foo();
}
```

Though, netbeans highlighted this implementation approach and recommended:

```java
collection.forEach((obj) -> {
    foo();
});
```

Why would this be preferable? Is there a standard for Java (similar to PEP8 for Python) that recommends the functional approach over the prior implementation strategy?

What, if anything, is changing under the hood between these two approaches?

This seems to be a difference of syntactic sugar?

Comment: There's no reason to make this change. It's mostly stylistic.

Comment: In this case, it has not much value to change one to the other. `forEach` utilizes the stream api which is associated with functional style programming, the other is a classic enhanced loop. Both are equally readable.

Comment: Seems pretty verbose for an otherwise identical approach? Performance changes? @Unmitigated

Comment: _"... Is there a standard for Java ..."_, no.  I imagine it's just a recommendation.

Comment: @f1sh The `Iterable#forEach(Consumer)` method does not utilize streams. Or, more accurately, the [default implementation](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/ce4e6e2bd704a90abc8e8e1586325769076c208a/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Iterable.java#L72) does not use streams (nor am I aware of any implementation that does, and I find it unlikely any implementation would).

Comment: @Slaw damn, i confused it with `stream().forEach()` and you are correct.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with either one but one may be more readable: one statement vs a loop.  To print each numbers in a list of integer: ``` list.forEach(System.out::println);```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly a matter of style.

For example, `Iterable#forEach` is implemented in OpenJDK by just using an enhanced for loop:

```java
default void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(action);
    for (T t : this) {
        action.accept(t);
    }
}
```

The main difference between using an enhanced for loop and `forEach` is that you can only access effectively final local variables in the `Consumer` passed to `forEach`. If you want to assign to local variables, then an enhanced for loop is clearly the better choice.